# XSL count continuous nodes

Tags: xslt

I have xml like

```
<tr>
 <td class="x">1</td>
 <td class="x">2</td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td class="x">4</td>
 <td class="x">5</td>
 <td class="x">6</td>
 <td class="x">7</td>
</tr>
```

and I want the result to be using xsl is:

```
\cont{1-2}
\cont{4-7}
```

can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to solve that with XSLT 2.0 or 1.0? 2.0 has `<for-each-group select="td" group-adjacent="@class = 'x'">` so that way it should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation is both short (25 lines) and efficient (uses keys):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="td[@class='x']"
  use="concat(generate-id(..),
              '+',generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                                 [not(self::td and @class='x')][1])
              )"/>  

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vGroup" 
       select="key('kFollowing', concat(generate-id(),'+'))"/>
  <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat('\cont{{',$vGroup[1],'-',$vGroup[last()],'}}','&#xA;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
   "key('kFollowing', concat(generate-id(..),'+', generate-id()))"/>
  <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat('\cont{{',$vGroup[1],'-',$vGroup[last()],'}}','&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="td[@class='x']|text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<tr>
    <td class="x">1</td>
    <td class="x">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="x">4</td>
    <td class="x">5</td>
    <td class="x">6</td>
    <td class="x">7</td>
</tr>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
  \cont{1-2}
  \cont{4-7}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are nice ways of doing it, and there are nasty ways of doing it. I haven't got enough time to think of a nice way, how does this grab you?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="td[@class='x']">
        <xsl:variable name="currentNum" select="number(text())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="prevNum" select="number(preceding-sibling::td[@class='x'][1]/text())"/>
        <xsl:if test="($currentNum - 1) != $prevNum and $currentNum &gt; 0 and following-sibling::td[@class='x']">
            <xsl:variable name="following" select="following-sibling::td[@class='x']"/>
            <xsl:if test="number($following[1]/text()) = ($currentNum + 1)">
            \cont{<xsl:value-of select="$currentNum"/>-<xsl:call-template name="findend">
                    <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$currentNum"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$following"/>
                </xsl:call-template>}
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="findend">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="start"/>
    <xsl:variable name="current" select="number($nodes[1]/text())"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($nodes) &lt; 2">
            <xsl:value-of select="$current"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="number($nodes[2]/text()) != ($current + 1)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$current"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="findend">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$current"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output is

```
\cont{1-2}
\cont{4-7}
```

I made the assumption that if you only had one number you didn't want a continue, so you don't get \cont{1-1}, and that they had to be in sequence and that they have to be in class='x'.

With a bit more time, you could come up with something prettier!

As an explanation though, it goes through looking for a td[@class='x'] whos number doesn't equal the previous one + 1 (ie, there was no number or it wasn't contiguous). If it finds one, it checks the next number is this number + 1, to avoid the case of the cont{1-1}, then it calls a recursive template that looks for and prints the end

Answer (score 1):

Here is some XSLT 1.0 approach using a key and modes (but those mainly to avoid complex template match patterns):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" 
  match="td[@class = 'x'][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::td[@class = 'x']]]"
  use="generate-id(
         preceding-sibling::td[
           @class = 'x' and 
           not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::td[@class = 'x']])
         ][1]
       )"/>

<xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="td[@class = 'x' and not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::td[@class = 'x']])]" mode="start"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td[@class = 'x']" mode="start">
  <xsl:text>\cont{</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', generate-id())[last()]" mode="end"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td[@class = 'x']" mode="end">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>}&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That stylesheet, when applied on

```
<tr>
 <td class="x">1</td>
 <td class="x">2</td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td class="x">4</td>
 <td class="x">5</td>
 <td class="x">6</td>
 <td class="x">7</td>
</tr>
```

outputs

```
\cont{1-2}
\cont{4-7}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest stylesheet I could come up with that solves your problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="td[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::td][@class='x'])]">
        <xsl:text>\cont{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::td[
                not(following-sibling::*[1][self::td][@class='x'])][1]"/>
        <xsl:text>}&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="td"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**: First, we match every `td` whose immediately preceding sibling is not itself a `td` with a `class` attribute equal to `x`. These are the start nodes, so we use their values as the start of each sequence.

For the end of the sequence we use the next `td` that does not have as its immediately following sibling another `td` whose `class` is `x`.

All other nodes are ignored.